# Trying to access a file share from a Wi-Fi router through a switch - can't see the share

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

So I've got a machine connected to Wi-Fi, and that Wi-Fi router is connected to the switch to get its internet access. That switch is where the machine with the file share is located. Other hard wired machines connected directly to the switch CAN access the file share with no issues.

I'm assuming it is something to do with the Wi-Fi router not being inside the same IP subnet but need some guidance on setting up the Wi-Fi router to get its IP address from the switch.

I've been doing some research and I believe I should be able to turn DHCP off, set the Wi-Fi router IP address to match the IP range of the switch (192.168.1.200) and the gateway to 192.168.1.1 which should then allow the machine connected to the Wi-Fi to see the file share.

Am I on track or way off base?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. If you disable DHCP on the end router it will become a Access Point/switch. As you said assign a IP to access it through webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling DHCP service on the Wi-Fi home gateway is part of the solution, but not the whole thing. To make it just a transparent bridge between wireless and wired, you also need to disable NAT.

Some home gateways don't let you disable NAT, in which case you should just disable DHCP service and then plug the gateway's **LAN** port into the upstream switch. Home gateways almost always bridge between LAN and WLAN, even if they don't let you set it to bridge between [W]LAN and WAN.